# MySQL Query Optimization - Random Record

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a terrible time with a MySQL query. I've spent most of my weekend and most of my day today attempting to make this query run a bit faster. I've made it considerably faster, but I know I can make it better.

```
SELECT m.id,other_fields,C.contacts_count FROM marketingDatabase AS m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) as contacts_count, rid 
  FROM contacts 
  WHERE status = 'Active' AND install_id = 'XXXX' GROUP BY rid) as C
 ON C.rid = m.id 
WHERE (RAND()*2612<50) 
  AND do_not_call != 'true' 
  AND `ACTUAL SALES VOLUME` >= '800000'  
  AND `ACTUAL SALES VOLUME` <= '1200000' 
  AND status = 'Pending'
  AND install_id = 'XXXXX' 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

I have an index on 'install_id', 'category' and 'status' but the EXPLAIN shows it was sorting based on 9100 rows.

My Explain is here:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/jas-so-question/Screen+Shot+2012-03-13+at+12.34.04+AM.png

Anybody have any suggestions on what I can do to make this a bit faster? The entire point of the query is to select a random record from an account's records (install_id) that matches certain criteria like sales volume, status and do_not_call. I'm currently gathering 25 records and caching it (using PHP) so I only have to run this query once every 25 requests, but I'm already dealing with thousands of requests per day. It currently takes 0.2 seconds to run. I realize that by using ORDER BY RAND() I'm already taking a major performance hit, but it's just sorting 25 rows.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT: I forgot to mention that the 'contact_sort' index is on the 'contacts' table, and indexes install_id, status, and rid. (rid references Record ID in marketingDatabase so it knows which record a contact belongs to.

**EDIT 2: The 2612 number in the query represents the number of rows in marketingDatabase that match the criteria (install_id, status, actual sales volume, etc.)

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html
There are restrictions and complexities that arise when using GROUP BY and indexes. To quote the manual "The most important preconditions for using indexes for GROUP BY are that all GROUP BY columns reference attributes from the same index, and that the index stores its keys in order (for example, this is a BTREE index and not a HASH index)." You are grouping by a non-indexed field, and also selecting and ordering the entire table in the sub-query.

I think (not sure) that ordering by RAND() is also a bad idea.

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() is a very, very [bad idea](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql).

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a bad idea, although I've read because the ORDER BY RAND() is only ordering 25 rows, it's not that big of a deal. Am I wrong?
How should I look to fix it and still get a random record? I do not have any column that is auto-increment without gaps...my id column is auto-increment but has gaps where rows have been deleted.

Comment: I think that `WHERE (RAND()*2612<50)` means MySQL still needs to calculate a random value for every single row in the table. Presumably that's what makes the query so slow?

Comment: Look at this it might give you some inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495446/how-to-get-random-records-from-each-category-in-mysql/31496011?noredirect=1#comment50972156_31496011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with a few queries, and I don't think you'll ever be able to get a indexed query to work with RAND(), especially when you're using it in both a WHERE clause and an ORDER BY clause. If at all possible, I'd introduce the random element in my PHP logic, and probably look at whether two simple queries made more sense than one fairly complex one. Added to that, you have LEFT OUTER JOIN on a random result set, which may also be increasing the amount of work that has to be done a lot.

In summary, my guess would be - rewrite to exclude RAND, see if you can get rid of the LEFT OUTER JOIN. Two straightforward indexed queries with a bit of PHP in between may be a lot better.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How should I look to go about this? Query all records in the DB that meet the criteria then use array_rand() to pick a random element?

Comment: Difficult to say, because I don't really know why you need the random, element, but yes, that sounds reasonable. You only have 2612 entries, so returning the entire table isn't too terrible (depending what's in it). At least the query will be cached, so it will be a doddle from the view of MySQL and probably PHP too.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not see your index definitions, I am not sure they are correct. The query would benefit from the following indexes:

1. a composite index (install_id, status, rid) on the `contacts`
2. a composite index (install_id, status, `ACTUAL SALES VOLUME`) on `marketingDatabase`

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I currently have for indexes.